# How to use has_archive but disable feed per post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, feed, custom-post-type-archives

What is the best way to disable feeds per post type but keep has_archive enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue today. I don't know if it's the best way, but here's how I solved it (with `has_archive` still set to true, of course):

```
// First we remove WP default feed actions
// If we stop here, feeds would be disabled altogether
remove_action('do_feed_rdf', 'do_feed_rdf', 10, 1);
remove_action('do_feed_rss', 'do_feed_rss', 10, 1);
remove_action('do_feed_rss2', 'do_feed_rss2', 10, 1);
remove_action('do_feed_atom', 'do_feed_atom', 10, 1);

// Now we add our own actions, which point to our own feed function
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'my_do_feed', 10, 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'my_do_feed', 10, 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'my_do_feed', 10, 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'my_do_feed', 10, 1);

// Finally, we do the post type check, and generate feeds conditionally
function my_do_feed() {
    global $wp_query;
    $no_feed = array('cpt_1', 'cpt_2');
    if(in_array($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'], $no_feed)) {
        wp_die(__('This is not a valid feed address.', 'textdomain'));
    }
    else {
        do_feed_rss2($wp_query->is_comment_feed);
    }
}
```

Please note that this will cause all feeds to generate as RSS 2.0, when they do generate, but you get general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working in a theme by checking if we're on the archive page for an array of custom post types and then removing the feed link actions:

```
function themename_remove_feed_links() {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( array( 'gallery', 'client', 'testimonial', 'slideshow' ) ) ) {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
        remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'themename_remove_feed_links' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but it should be as simple as:

```
register_post_type( 'slug', array(
    'has_archive' => true,

    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'slug',
        'feeds' => false,
    ),
);
```